# ElasticSearch Kibana monitor data starts to loss data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We have a small ElasticSearch 6.3.2 cluster with 5 nodes. All was good for a while until this morning. The monitoring charts in Kibana looks this way:
[image]

And it's happening on all the monitoring indexes. Can anyone shed some light on this? I have no clue why it starts behave like this. We didn't do any change on ElasticSearch cluster or kibana recently.